# Deleting from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in ASP.net, C#. I am expecting to delete the row in a report returned with the help of `GridView`. The beginning of the specific code was like:

```
Label Lblno = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lblno")
```

What does this line mean? Please explain:

```
(Label)Gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lblno")
```

I couldn't get a flow of code for this particular line. I don't know what it is.

```
e.RowIndex,FindControl("Lblno")
```

Comment: specifically, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Your title and your question don't match up.  Your question is about deleting from a GridView, but your code shows you finding a label by it's control id and through casting gaining a reference to it

Comment: I couldn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

`Lblno` is a label Name which is placed in the `GridCell`

`e.RowIndex` is the index of current Row which is clicked/Selected.

`FindControl()` is to find the control which is placed in the `GridRow`.

`(Label)Gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lblno")` says that find the control named `Lblno` from the row index of (`e.RowIndex`) `GridView1` and that controls is a type of `Label`